# Prevent unnecessary re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

This is an onscreen keyboard component.

I don't feel like rewriting all the properties for a single key button every time because that would make the code look ugly, so I opted for an extra component that I treat as a "key button shorthand", problem is every time I press a key I notice the rest of the keys also rerender because of the state change, what's an alternative solution to prevent this?

```
function Keyboard({ setState }: { setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>> }) {
  let keyInterval = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>()
  let keyTimeout = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>()

  function keyDownBehaviour(action: () => void) {
    action()
    keyTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      keyInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
        action()
      }, 50)
    }, 500)
  }

  function keyUpBehaviour() {
    clearInterval(keyInterval.current)
    clearTimeout(keyTimeout.current)
  }

  function Key({ text }: { text: string }) {
    return (
      <Button
        className="text-lg p-0 w-12"
        variant="outline"
        onMouseDown={() => keyDownBehaviour(() => setState(prevAnswer => prevAnswer + text))}
        onMouseUp={keyUpBehaviour}
        onMouseLeave={keyUpBehaviour}
      >
        {text}
      </Button>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col mt-2 gap-2 w-auto">
      <div className="flex gap-[0.2rem] sm:gap-2 w-auto">
        <Key text="b" />
        <Key text="a" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not define components inside of your component but explicitly make it its own component. This way you can [memoize](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) the component.

From the react documentation: *"`memo` lets you skip re-rendering a component when its props are unchanged."*

In your case you can use it like:

```
import { memo } from 'react' 

const Key = memo(function Key({ text, setState }: { text: string, setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>> }) {
  let keyInterval = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>()
  let keyTimeout = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>()

  function keyDownBehaviour(action: () => void) {
    action()
    keyTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      keyInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
        action()
      }, 50)
    }, 500)
  }

  function keyUpBehaviour() {
    clearInterval(keyInterval.current)
    clearTimeout(keyTimeout.current)
  }

  return (
      <Button
        className="text-lg p-0 w-12"
        variant="outline"
        onMouseDown={() => keyDownBehaviour(() => setState(prevAnswer => prevAnswer + text))}
        onMouseUp={keyUpBehaviour}
        onMouseLeave={keyUpBehaviour}
      >
        {text}
    </Button>
  )

})
```

You can then just use it like

```
return (
    <div className="flex flex-col mt-2 gap-2 w-auto">
      <div className="flex gap-[0.2rem] sm:gap-2 w-auto">
        <Key text="b" setstate={setState} />
        <Key text="a" setstate={setState} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

If the other keys are still rendering you might need to add a custom [comparison function](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#specifying-a-custom-comparison-function)

```
// ...

        {text}
    </Button>
  )

}, (oldProps, newProps) => {
  // Only check if the text props changes
  // if not, react considers it as the same component and won't re-render
  return oldProps.text === newProps.text
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can prevent unnecessary rerenders in react using multiple hooks such as useCallback, useMemo, useLayOutEffect, useEffect but the most suitable method for the example you privided is `React.memo` which memoizes the rendered output of the component based on it's props preventing unnecessary renders when props remains same.

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

function Key({ text, setState }: { text: string, setState: 
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>> }) {
  const keyDownBehaviour = () => {
    setState((prevAnswer) => prevAnswer + text);
  };

  return (
    <Button
      className="text-lg p-0 w-12"
      variant="outline"
      onMouseDown={keyDownBehaviour}
      onMouseUp={() => {}}
      onMouseLeave={() => {}}
    >
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
}

// Memoize the Key component to prevent unnecessary rerenders
const MemoizedKey = memo(Key);

function Keyboard({ setState }: { setState: 
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>> }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col mt-2 gap-2 w-auto">
      <div className="flex gap-[0.2rem] sm:gap-2 w-auto">
        <MemoizedKey text="b" setState={setState} />
        <MemoizedKey text="a" setState={setState} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

React is a super simple construct.  Your App is a "tree of components" where the top component and is the only component without a parent.

Components (which are simply JS functions) will Render (i.e. the function will be executed) under only 2 cases:

- a state variable of the component itself is modified by the "set state function"
- the component's parent renders

Since your Keyboard component is being passed down a "set state function" of its parent (`setState`), and Keyboard calls that function, then the Keyboard is changing a state value in its parent...

....which will cause the parent to re-render...

....which will cause ALL of the parent's children to re-render...

...which will cause all of Keyboard's children to re-render...

The question is: do you actually want (or need) to have Keyboard  updating the state of Keyboard's parent?  Or is there a cleaner/better way to communicate the event press without updating state in the parent and causing a cascading of renders?